# Python urllib2 urlopen doesn't run CakePHP code at url

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a CakePHP site, and a specific function that is routed to http://example.com/mycontroller/myfunction

I am trying to create a python script that I can run on a cron job that will call this function on a regular interval.  My python script looks as follows:

```
import urllib2

urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/mycontroller/myfunction")
```

The script runs, but the function isn't called; that is, the result is not the same as if I visit that URL in my browser.

How can I mimic the same action as visiting the url in my browser, from this python script?

Alternatively, is there another obvious way to run this specific PHP function on a regular interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't doing anything fancy (e.g., dependent on client-side javascript or other browser behavior) for your page to run, you're probably better off using a utility made for that purpose (i.e. curl or wget) rather than writing a custom script.

For example, you can use the following command directly in your crontab:

```
curl -silent http://example.com/mycontroller/myfunction
```

If you are truly dependent on making a request exactly like a browser (fetching linked images, scripts, and stylesheets and executing javascript), you'll probably need to use a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Thanks!  Stupid me. I realized that the reason it wasn't working because of CakePHP authentication - I was requiring a login.  Currently trying to figure that out.

Comment: @chambo622 That is trickier.  I've had success in the past using the Mechanize module for managing multi-request processes (like hitting a sign in page and then accessing a controlled resource).  You can find some info on that here: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet/